# VS code theme doesn't show up in integrated Jupyter notebook

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I've installed Dracula At Night theme in VS code but it doesn't show up in Jupyter Notebook.

VS Code Theme:

[image]

Jupyter Theme:

[image]

How do i fix this issue?